# Fedora /etc/sysctl.conf not loaded upon boot

Tags: fedora, sysctl

I am running Fedora 27 with kernel 4.14.5 and have a problem that `/etc/sysctl.conf` is not being loaded upon boot.

If I run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

after boot, my settings are loaded and everything works fine.

What do I need to do to enable the loading of `/etc/sysctl.conf` or what alternatives are there to load it?

Comment: Be careful with potential alternatives, because depending on what you have in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, some sysctl settings need to be read early at boot time (e.g. before device creation), otherwise they may not have any effect. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11655 for instance about such particular settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In systemd operating systems like Fedora, loading these settings is done with the `systemd-sysctl` commmand, run by the `systemd-sysctl` service.  Your problem is that you have put the settings in the wrong configuration file.

`systemd-sysctl` does not read `/etc/sysctl.conf`.  It reads a whole bunch of `*.conf` files in (amongst other places) the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory.  You should create such a file and put your settings there.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). [`systemd-sysctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysctl.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). [`sysctl.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your root's CRON:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Paste the following:

```
@reboot /sbin/sysctl --load=/etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: This will work, but is a kludge around a different configuration problem.

Comment: @mattdm I myself am using it. Tell me in detail, what problems it might cause as for your claim. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the normal way to configure this. There's many ways to do things, and if you like a certain way, that's fine, but the other answer represents the standard way. That's important if you ever work on other systems, or if other people work on yours, or if you want the knowledge to transfer for a job or something.

Comment: Additionally, this will trigger after a reboot _when cron starts_. The `systemd-sysctl` service usually starts very early. That's _probably_ not going to cause a problem in real life, but could, depending on what you want to set.